# Counting non-similar matrices over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb F_q$ be the field of $q$ elements where $q\geq2$.

Denote
$SL_2(\mathbb F_q) = \{A \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb F_q): \det (A) = 1\} $, Where $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb F_q)$ is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb F_q$.

How many pairwise non-similar matrices are there in $SL_2(\mathbb F_q)$?

---

My attempt was to try and observe something from the characteristic polynomials, but I haven't found any significant breakthrough yet.

Comment: Hint: try to distinguish the cases where the characteristic polynomial has $1$ or $2$ distinct roots over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

Comment: @CaptainLama So in those cases, the matrix has a jordan canonical form. I still don't get why $\mathbb F_{q^2}$, is it because it is algebraically closed (I'm not sure if it is). Also, even though I know the number of jordan canonical forms, how do I count how many matrices correspond to each form.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, then. I thought the goal was to compute the number of similarity classes, not the number of matrices in each class.

Comment: @CaptainLama The question is to find the number of pairwise non-similar matrices. Don't I need to find the number of matrices in each class to do that.